# How can I read/get some specific informations from txt file using Java

Tags: java, list

I'm facing some difficulties to get some specific information from many *.log files using Java. I've spent some hours looking into this forum but I didn't found something like I need.
First of all I wanna get those information and print them at the console, just to make sure all information that I need are working fine.
The data from *.log file are this kind below:

```
Date Logged:        10-22-2014 11:11:00 AM
Task Name:      PROJECT_X_X00_SPI3
User ID:        Operator Mode
System:         PP/PS Series FlashCORE
Machine ID:     12345678910

Device:         MACRONIX MX25L6473EM2 SO8
Data Source:        X:\XPTO\PROJECT\BINARYFILE.bin
Sumcheck:       12345678
Process:        Continuity/Blank Check/ID Check/Erase/Program/Verify/Auto Secure/Mark/Vision
Process Status:     Job Begin Status: New Job, Job End Status: Stopped
TLWin Session ID:   < none >

Job Start Time:     10-22-2014 03:38:57 AM
Job End Time:       10-22-2014 11:11:00 AM
Devices Total:      5051
Devices Passed:     5041
Devices Failed:     10
Overall Device Yield:   99.80%

Task Description:   MX25L6473EM

Nominal Throughput: 722 dph
Job Throughput:     679 dph
```

Here's the code that I made in order to read all data from *.log files:

```
public class ReadingDataTxt {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dir = "F:\\XPTO";

    File file = new File(dir);

    for (String arq : file.list()) {
        if (arq.endsWith(".log")) {
            System.out.println("--------->" + arq + "<---------");
            try {
                System.out.println(reading(dir + "\\" + arq));
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}

private static String reading(String dir) throws Exception {
    String line = " ", content = " ";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir)));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            content = new StringBuilder(content).append(line.concat("\n")).toString();

        }
    }

    br.close();
    return content;
}
```

}

The most important information that I need is the data a front the first String (strong highlight):
Date Logged: **10-22-2014**
Task Name: **PROJECT_X_X00_SPI3**
Device: **MACRONIX MX25L6473EM2 SO8**
Devices Total: **5051**
Devices Failed:     **10**
Overall Device Yield: **99.80%**

The second step will be make a CSV file in order to place these information into the data base.

Thanks so much!

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What information you need to get?

Comment: You should definitely not load each entire file into memory in order to read & print it (I'm referring to the "content" variable). You can print line by line.

Comment: So, split each line using `:` as the separator, check what the first value is, and if it is one of your searched keys, add the value to the data structure you want.

Comment: Hint: **never never never** leave your catch blocks empty. That means: you ran into an error, and you **ignore** that. "Woha, my program doesn't work; and I have no idea what it is doing!" Yeah, sure, you are throwing away all error messages!

Comment: The other **crazy** part: do **not** create a new StringBuilder within each loop run. Create the StringBuilder **outside** of the loop; and just append the stuff you want to append.

Comment: I want something like an excel table. The column name will be Date Logged, Task Name, Device, Total, Passed, Failed and Yield. `Date Logged Task Name Device Devices Total Devices Passed Devices Failed Yield
10-22-2014 PROJECT_X_X00_SPI3 MACRONIX MX25L6473EM2 SO8 5051 5041 10 99.80%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a pseudo-code

Either you can use `StringBuilder` itself and the parsing logic given below to generate the required string. Just make sure you are defining `StringBuilder` outside of any loop.

OR

you can take a map `Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();` and populate it by required key/value(s). So that you can extract it in some other method by keys.


 now for each line, you can do

```
String[] tokens = line.trim().split(":");
if(tokens.length >= 2){
        data.put(tokens[0].trim(), tokens[1].trim());
        // or append to stringbuilder
}
```

Additionally you can also put up a check there for the specific tokens(keys) only which you want to put into map.

Comment: Hi Shubham, thanks to share some information. I've changed the code as your recommended, please check it out: `String[] tokens = line.trim().split(":");
 
   if (tokens.length >= 2) {
    String dataLogged = tokens[0];
    String taskName = tokens [1];
    String device = tokens [2];
    String deviceTotal = tokens [3];
    String devicePassed = tokens [4];
    String deviceFailed = tokens [5];
    String yield = tokens [6];
    map.put(dataLogged.trim(), taskName.trim(), device.trim(), deviceTotal.trim(), devicePassed.trim(), deviceFailed.trim(), yield.trim());`

Comment: @EvertonWcks I would recommend you to first read about the basic concepts involved in this question like arrays, String splitting etc. All I mean to say is first work on specific small problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java version](https://github.com/thekrakken/java-grok) of Grok Parser. You can define a pattern and all the lines in the file that match the pattern will get parsed.